# How to put a list of values in a tensor at given positions with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm looking for a (the best ?) way to put a set of values in a tensor at given positions ; or an operation involving the tensor, the list of values and the list of indexes, and outputing the same result (ie. with no mutable Variable).

The equivalent code in NumPy would be:

```py
inds = np.array([1, 3, 5])
values = np.array([.5, .6, .1])

output = np.zeros((10,))

# Here is the line that I want to reproduce in TF
output[inds] = values
```

I've figured out how to do it for a single value (ie. `output[inds] = 1`) but I didn't find any solution for a list of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd):

```
import tensorflow as tf

inds = tf.constant([1, 3, 5])
values = tf.constant([.5, .6, .1])
# Add one dimension to indices and scatter
output = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(inds, 1), values, (10,))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output))
```

Output:

```
[0.  0.5 0.  0.6 0.  0.1 0.  0.  0.  0. ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! The documentation of `tf.scatter_nd` lead me to the `tf.scatter_nd_add` operation which is what I was looking for.